# Vertically align text in <a> element with CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Can someone explain how I vertically align the text in `<a>` elements - so both text appears in the middle of the red box?

http://jsfiddle.net/WeKtX/

Here's my *HTML*:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">this is a link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">this is an even longer link</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my *CSS*:

```
li {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0}
li a {width:100px;float:left;background:red;margin-right:20px;height:40px}
```

Many thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to center the text horizontally then try:

```
text-align: center;
```

If you want to center the text vertically then try:

```
line-height: 40px; //Where 40px is the height of your parent element
```

Keep in mind, that when using line-height, it will only work on **one line** of text.  If you want to do multiple lines of text then I'm afraid you have to specify a height to the text and then use `position: absolute;` on the text with `position: relative;` on the parent element.

For your multi-line example I'd try something like [the following jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WeKtX/10/):

```
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    background:red;
}

li a {
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I think I'll use a class to ignore `line-height` on the multiple line text ones.

Comment: Was I able to help @michaelmcgurk?  If so, mark my answer correct so it can help other people in the future!

Comment: Hehe, I'm still working on it at my end - it looks to have done the trick. Couple more minutes ;-) Thanks again.

Comment: Totally, glad to be of help!  Let me know if there's anything else you're confused about.